# Does the Yoneda Embedding Theorem really follow from the Yoneda Lemma?

Tags: category-theory

Suppose $\mathbb{C}$ is a locally small category, and denote by $[\mathbb{C}^{\mathrm{op}}, \mathrm{Set}]$ its category of presheaves.

Define the functor $F : \mathbb{C} \to [\mathbb{C}^{\mathrm{op}}, \mathrm{Set}]$ by mapping each object $X$ to its presheaf $FX = \mathrm{Hom}(-, X)$, and each arrow $f : X \to Y$ to the natural transformation $Ff : FX \Rightarrow FY$ whose components are obtained by postcomposition with $f$, i.e. $(Ff)_Z = f \circ - : \mathrm{Hom}(Z, X) \to \mathrm{Hom}(Z, Y)$.

The Yoneda Embedding theorem states

> *(YET)* $F$ is fully faithful.

This is often said to follow from the Yoneda Lemma, which in many places (e.g. [nLab](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/Yoneda+lemma)) is stated in terms of the existence of a bijection, e.g.:

> *(YL)* There exists a bijection
> $$[\mathbb{C}^{\mathrm{op}}, \mathrm{Set}](\mathrm{Hom}(-,X), \mathrm{Hom}(-,Y)) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(X, Y).$$

(I have specialised to the case of two hom functors since this is all that is needed in this question.)

In contrast, in some places (e.g. in [Emily Riehl's book](https://emilyriehl.github.io/files/context.pdf)), I have seen an alternative statement of the Yoneda Lemma that makes explicit the form of the bijection it describes:

> *(YL+)* The map that takes a natural transformation $\alpha : \mathrm{Hom}(-,X) \Rightarrow \mathrm{Hom}(-,Y)$ to $\alpha_X(id_X) : X \to Y$ is a bijection.

I can see how to obtain YET from YL+, since once we know that the map $\alpha \mapsto \alpha_X(\mathrm{id}_X)$ is a bijection, it is straightforward to check that this map can be inverted via $F$. (Specifically, if we denote this bijection by $\Psi$, it is straightforward to show that $\Psi(F(f)) = f$ for all $f : X \to Y$.)
However, I can't see this directly from YL, since it is not clear that the isomorphism of sets that YL refers to is in fact the one induced by $F$.

Am I missing something that would make YET a more obvious consequence of YL directly? (One thing I have left out here is the naturality of the bijections in YL and YL+ - would this help?) Or is YL+ really what is needed to obtain YET without effectively reproving the Yoneda Lemma from scratch?

Comment: If you have a proof of (YL) that doesn't involve $F$, then you might not be able to get (YET) as stated, because (YET) is about a particular functor.  But, the usual proof of (YT) uses $F$.  So, the corollary is more a result of the proof of (YT), rather than the theorem itself.

Comment: The statement (YL) is careless. It is correct, but (YL+) is what is needed in practice, as you observe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an interesting variation of the Yoneda lemma at play here.

Note that a transformation with components $\phi_{X,Y}\colon C(X,Y)\to D(FX,FY)$ given by $\phi_{X,Y}:f\mapsto Ff$ is natural if and only if $F$ is a functor. Moreover, $F$ is full, resp. faithful, resp. fully faithful, if and only if the components are surjections, resp. injections, resp. bijections

The variation is then this: any natural transformation $\alpha\colon C(X,Y)\to D(FX,FY)$ is of the form $D(\beta,FY)\circ\phi=D(FX,\beta)\circ\phi$ for a natural transformation $\beta$ from $F$ to itself with components $\beta_X=\alpha_{X,X}(\mathrm{id}_X)$.

Indeed, naturality in $Y$ of $\alpha\colon C(X,Y)\to D(FX,FY)$ implies $\alpha_{X,Y}(f)=\alpha_{X,Y}\circ C(X,f)(\mathrm{id_X})=D(FX,Ff)\circ\alpha_{X,X}(\mathrm{id}_X)=Ff\circ\beta_X$ where $\beta_X=\alpha_{X,X}(\mathrm{id_X})\in D(FX,FY)$, while naturaliry in $X$ implies $\alpha_{X,Y}(f)=\beta_Y\circ Ff$. In particular, $Ff\circ\beta_X=\alpha_{X,Y}(f)=\beta_Y\circ Ff$, asserts exactly that $\beta$ is a natural transformation from $F$ to itself such that $D(\beta,FY)\circ\phi=\alpha=D(FX,\beta)\circ\phi$.

We now claim that if $\alpha_{X,X}$ are surjective, then $\beta$ is a natural isomorphism from $F$ to itself, whence $D(FX,\beta)$ and $D(\beta,FY)$ are natural bijections from $D(FX,FY)$ to $D(FX,FY)$ by which $\alpha$ and $\phi$ are related. In particular, $\alpha$ a natural bijection implies $\phi$ is a natural bijection, e.g. (YL-wtih-naturality) implies (YET).

Indeed, if $\alpha_{X,X}$ are surjective, then $\mathrm{id}_{FX}=Fs\circ j_X=j_X\circ Ft$ for some $s,t\in C(X,X)$, whence $Fs=Ft=\beta_X^{-1}$ are the unique two-sided inverses of $\beta_X$, from which follows that the natural transformation $\beta$ has an inverse $\beta^{-1}$.